# NoReverse Match in Mezzanine - I am using get_absolute_url for slug field

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am currently developing a mezzanine project. I always get "NoReverseMatch":

```
Reverse for 'download' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'read-metxt-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

In my previous app before I used Mezzanine, there was no error. I just copy-pasted the code and modify it accordingly.

Sorry for asking the same question. I know there are other similar questions as mine, but none of them is working.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
import os

# Create your models here.
class ReportOutline_File(models.Model):
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)
report_outline = models.FileField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('txttoppt: download', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.report_outline.name) #slugifying the title
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = ReportOutline_File.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
    return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)

    return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)
        print instance.slug

pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=ReportOutline_File)
```

urls.py (main: mezzanine)

```
urlpatterns += [
   url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
   url("^convert-to-ppt/", include("toppt.urls", namespace="txttoppt")),]
```

urls.py (app)

```
from .views import (
    converttexttoppt_func,
    download
)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^", converttexttoppt_func, name="converttexttoppt"),
    url(r"^download/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", download, name='download')]
```

views.py

```
def converttexttoppt_func(request):

form = ReportOutlineForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
context = {
    "form": form
}
return render(request, "texttoppt.html", context)

def download(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(ReportOutline_File, slug=slug)
    #more codes in between....
    return render(request, "download.html", context)
```

Please help! Thank you. I've been looking for solution for this error for two days now! Tsk!

Answer (score 0):

The slug you're providing includes numbers, but the url doesn't match numbers

```
u'read-metxt-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10'
```

so you need to update your url accordingly

```
url(r"^download/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)/$", download, name='download')
```

Comment: It is still not working. Actually, this works on the previous app I created, but when I used mezzanine, it does not work. Maybe because of the mezzanine?

Comment: I also tried to make 'get_absolute_url'  changed to  'return "download/%s/" %(self.slug)' . It does not give me any error, but it is not rendering the 'download.html'. Instead, it remains on the same page and nothing happens, except for the url in the address bar.

Comment: Your converttexttoppt_func url is also matching everything, change that to `"^$"` or similar

Comment: I tried that already, that does not work. Again, this code works on the previous app, but when I tried to convert this to Mezzanine, everything went crazy. :/